# Content Security Policy not working for external script file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, content-security-policy, mixed-content

Chrome is blocking an HTTP file due to Mixed Content. I have added to Content-Security-Policy to the header but still no working.

This is what I built in C#:

Filter:

```
public class ContentSecurityPolicyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;          
        response.AddHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';  script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class MyController
{
    [ContentSecurityPolicyFilter]
    public ActionResult MyAction(int? id)
    {
        // code...
        return View("Preview", model);
    }
}
```

Then the console says this:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://local.dev/MyController/MyAction' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.clientUrl.com/wp-content/themes/market/js/custom.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Any ideas? Basically, I want to allow an iframe to render an HTTP website. I was expecting to see warnings in the console instead of errors.

Comment: The only solution is to serve the `http://www.clientUrl.com/wp-content/themes/market/js/custom.js` content over HTTPS instead. Browsers otherwise won’t let you load HTTP insecure assets (mixed content) into an HTTPS document. And you can’t use CSP to override that behavior.